# .NET Framework Migration to 4.8 from 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I have two websites running in production both written in .NET 2.0. Say WebsiteA and WebsiteB. Now both these websites are referring some common class libraries which are also written in 2.0 framework.

We need to migrate WebsiteA to latest 4.8 framework. WebsiteB is out of scope now and will need to remain as it is.

I have migrated WebsiteA and the class libraries referred by only WebsiteA to 4.8.

But what about the shared class libraries between WebsiteA and WebsiteB ? Currently all are part of a sln file including the WebsiteA and WebsiteB.

Should I create a separate copy of the shared class libraries and migrate to 4.8 for WebsiteA ? Currently migrated WebsiteA is failing to refer the 2.0 class libraries.

I am using VS2017.

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Comment: Why would you even bother "upgrading" to .NET Framework 4.8, which is effectively dead?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in the decision making team. I know that NET Framework 4.8 won’t evolve anymore but decision is not mine. But 4..8 should be backward-compatible with components built with previous versions should work without modification.

Comment: You need to provide more context for "WebsiteA is failing to refer the 2.0 class libraries". Can you not add those DLLs as references? Do they not compile? Do they fail at runtime?

Comment: The shared library will need to be migrated also. So, should not create any problem anymore.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility  You will just have to try it. If not than migrate the shared DLLs as well.

Comment: Successfully migrate to 4.8. Everything was working fine but getting this strange issue in generated wsdl of asmx web service. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65086700/4222114